# Error initializing graphdriver installing docker on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04

I tried to install docker on Ubuntu 20.04 with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"
sudo apt install docker-ce
```

The docker daemon does not startup and the error is this one:

```
failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: devicemapper: Error running deviceCreate (CreatePool) dm_task_run failed
```

I tried changing the storage to `overlay` but did not work

Answer (score 3):

Go to the `/var/lib/docker` directory and check whether the `devicemapper` and `overlay2` directories exist at the same time. If they exist at the same time, delete the `devicemapper` directory and restart the docker service

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The OS was configured in a way that the load of kernel modules was disabled and docker was not able to `modprobe overlay` so it failed to start up.